# Dynamically add a value to a variable in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript

How to I dynamically add a value to a variable in a Javascript file? I have a Java application running on Glassfish.

I would like to place a value in a customer.properties file Ex: cust_name=Acme

Which would be read inside index.xhtml that has a link to the js file.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/read_the_name.js"></script>
```

read_the_name.js has "cust_name" that I would like the value to be read from customer.properties

Contents of read_the_name.js:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.NREUM||(NREUM={}), ... more code here ..., cust_name:""}
//]]>
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul, you're the winner! I tried your 2nd idea and it worked.

index.xhtml

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    var appId = "#{customerServiceBean.appId}";
  </script>

  <script> //add read_the_name.js to the index.html page if appId is available 
   if(typeof appId !== 'undefined' || appId !== null || appId > 0 ) {
     var custAppId = document.createElement('script');
     custAppId.type = "text/javascript";
     custAppId.src = "#{root}lib/new-relic/read_the_name.js";
     document.body.appendChild(custAppId);
   }
  </script>

 </head>
  ... more code here ...
</html>
```

read_the_name.js

```
//<![CDATA[
window.NREUM||(NREUM={}), ... more code here ..., cust_name:appId}
//]]>
```

customer.properties

```
appId=12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another js file that will export the customer config, for example customer_properties.js:

```
const properties = {
    cust_name = 'Acme'
};
module.exports = properties;
```

Then in read_the_name.js:

```
properties = require('./customer_properties');
do something with properties.cust_name
```

`read_the_name.js` would not have the customer properties hard-coded in, and you could dynamically generate `customer_properties.js`

Comment: Thanks Nima, I'll give this a try and report back on my results

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you're not going to change a static .js file with a new variable.

What you'll do instead is one of the following:

- Have your Java code generate the JavaScript file using whatever your favorite templating engine is (like you would your HTML).
- Have your JS remain "pure" but then have a  tag in your HTML that is generated by your Java code to set the variable before the javascript file is loaded
- Pass the variable in as a data-attribute on the script tag that calls the file (in which case you also need a way to find the right tag, e.g ID or classname, etc)
- Build your javascript files using something like webpack or grunt in the right context as when you set your properties file.

Comment: Thanks for all the options to try out, I'll keep you posted on my results